# how to use progress bar in WinForm Application in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

i need to use Progress bar in my application.

It takes more than two minutes to compete the process but it may vary based on the situation

Can i use progress Bar to show the the progress of the application without knowing the maximum limit and step value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have some idea about how long it will take you could just set the max to 100 and slowly update it but making sure that it'll never reach 100 before it's finished, and then when it is finished you just jump to 100. It looks a little funny, but it's fairly common still. If you have no idea at all how long it would take I'd suggest that a progress bar is not the solution, rather you'd want to use some other kind of animation to show progress without giving a false impression on how long it'll take (I really hate progress bars that go up to 95% or something and then jumps back to 40%).

Answer (score 5):

When the end condition is not known or cannot be calculated, the best it to give some indication to the user that the application is busy performing the requested operation.
In this case, the Progress Bar can be set to be used as a Marquee (An Ever Looping Progress Bar)
[link text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.progressbar.aspx)