# progress bar while excel file saving help please

Tags: vb.net, excel, vba

I have a form and a button on that form.When the user clicks on the button an MS-Excel sheet is generated from access database and saved in a particular location.As this generation of excel tkes sometime to complete,what i want to do is i want to show a progressbar loading till the entire sheet is generated.
Showing the progress bar will help the user to understand that the generating of excel is under process.

how can i do this any help pleas ?

this is my code :

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
     Try
        Dim saveFileDialog1 As New SaveFileDialog
        saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Excel File|*.xlsx"
        saveFileDialog1.Title = "Save an Excel File"
        saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
        If saveFileDialog1.FileName <> "" Then
            saveExcelFile(saveFileDialog1.FileName)
        End If
        MessageBox.Show("Excel file Saved!")
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
Public Sub saveExcelFile(ByVal FileName As String)
    Try
        Dim xls As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
        xls = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
        Dim sheet As Excel.Worksheet
        Dim i As Integer
        xls.Workbooks.Add()
        sheet = xls.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
        Dim row As Integer = 1
        Dim col As Integer = 1
        For i = 0 To Me.ListView1.Columns.Count - 1
            sheet.Cells(1, i + 1) = Me.ListView1.Columns(i).Text
        Next
        For i = 0 To Me.ListView1.Items.Count - 1
            For j = 0 To Me.ListView1.Items(i).SubItems.Count - 1
                sheet.Cells(i + 2, j + 1) = Me.ListView1.Items(i).SubItems(j).Text
            Next
        Next

        row += 1
        col = 1

        ' for the header 
        sheet.Rows(1).Font.Name = "DotumChe"
        sheet.Rows(1).Font.size = 15
        sheet.Rows(1).HorizontalAlignment = Excel.XlVAlign.xlVAlignCenter
        Dim mycol As System.Drawing.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#20B2AA")
        sheet.Rows(1).Font.color = mycol
        ' for all the sheet without header
        sheet.Range("a2", "z1000").Font.Name = "Arial"
        sheet.Range("a2", "z1000").Font.Size = 13
        sheet.Range("a2", "z1000").HorizontalAlignment = Excel.XlVAlign.xlVAlignCenter

        sheet.Range("A1:X1").EntireColumn.AutoFit()
        sheet.Range("A1:X1").EntireRow.AutoFit()

        xls.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs(FileName)
        xls.Workbooks.Close()
        xls.Quit()
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: is this window or web application

Comment: windows application @A.Goutam

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211298/how-to-use-progress-bar-in-winform-application-in-c-sharp concept can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First add a **ProgressBar control** in your form and set .Maximum = 100 
Second in your loop items add that line:

```
 ProgressBar1.Maximum = 100

 For i = 0 To Me.ListView1.Items.Count - 1
        For j = 0 To Me.ListView1.Items(i).SubItems.Count - 1
            sheet.Cells(i + 2, j + 1) = Me.ListView1.Items(i).SubItems(j).Text
        Next
```

**ProgressBar1.Value = CInt(( i / Me.ListView1.Items.Count)*100)**

```
Next
```

or something similar, I didn't try it but I think will work :)
 Have fun !

Answer (score 1):

Create a form in your application. Put a progress/thermometer bar on it. Set the maximum value to `Me.ListView1.Columns.Count * 2`, then:

```
    For i = 0 To Me.ListView1.Columns.Count - 1
        sheet.Cells(1, i + 1) = Me.ListView1.Columns(i).Text
        'increment progress bar counter by 1
        'refresh form
    Next
    For i = 0 To Me.ListView1.Items.Count - 1
        'increment progress bar counter by 1
        'refresh form
        For j = 0 To Me.ListView1.Items(i).SubItems.Count - 1
            sheet.Cells(i + 2, j + 1) = Me.ListView1.Items(i).SubItems(j).Text
        Next
    Next
```

Then close your form.

Comment: i'm new in .net can you give me the full code please @FreeMan

Comment: I'm newer than that in .Net. check out `CristiC777`'s answer, below.

Answer (score 1):

i solve the it :)
this is the answer :

```
        Dim x As Integer
        x = 100 - CInt((i / Me.ListView1.Items.Count) * 100)
        ProgressBar1.Increment(1)
        ProgressBar1.Value = CInt((i / Me.ListView1.Items.Count) * 100) + x
        Me.Refresh()
```

this the full code :

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    Dim saveFileDialog1 As New SaveFileDialog
    saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Excel File|*.xlsx"
    saveFileDialog1.Title = "Save an Excel File"
    If saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        If saveFileDialog1.FileName <> "" Then
            saveExcelFile(saveFileDialog1.FileName)
        End If
    End If
    MessageBox.Show("Excel file Saved!")

End Sub
Public Sub saveExcelFile(ByVal FileName As String)
    Try
        Dim xls As New Excel.Application
        Dim sheet As Excel.Worksheet
        Dim i As Integer
        xls.Workbooks.Add()
        sheet = xls.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
        Dim row As Integer = 1
        Dim col As Integer = 1
        For i = 0 To Me.ListView1.Columns.Count - 1
            sheet.Cells(1, i + 1) = Me.ListView1.Columns(i).Text
        Next
        For i = 0 To Me.ListView1.Items.Count - 1
            For j = 0 To Me.ListView1.Items(i).SubItems.Count - 1
                sheet.Cells(i + 2, j + 1) = Me.ListView1.Items(i).SubItems(j).Text
            Next
            Dim x As Integer
            x = 100 - CInt((i / Me.ListView1.Items.Count) * 100)
            ProgressBar1.Increment(1)
            ProgressBar1.Value = CInt((i / Me.ListView1.Items.Count) * 100) + x
            Me.Refresh()
        Next

        row += 1
        col = 1

        ' for the header 
        sheet.Rows(1).Font.Name = "Cooper Black"
        sheet.Rows(1).Font.size = 12
        sheet.Rows(1).HorizontalAlignment = Excel.XlVAlign.xlVAlignCenter
        Dim mycol As System.Drawing.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#148cf7")
        sheet.Rows(1).Font.color = mycol
        ' for all the sheet without header
        sheet.Range("a2", "z1000").Font.Name = "Arial"
        sheet.Range("a2", "z1000").Font.Size = 13
        sheet.Range("a2", "z1000").HorizontalAlignment = Excel.XlVAlign.xlVAlignCenter

        sheet.Range("A1:X1").EntireColumn.AutoFit()
        sheet.Range("A1:X1").EntireRow.AutoFit()

        xls.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs(FileName)
        xls.Workbooks.Close()
        xls.Quit()
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```